# Floating Point Exception - One Variable Stopped Getting Updated

Tags: c

everyone. Could anybody help me correct the code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main (void) {

    int first = 0, second = 0, product, count = 2, lcm = 0, countProduct = 0;

    printf("Enter the first integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &first);
    printf("Enter the second integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &second);

    product = -1;

    while (product % first != 0 && product % second != 0){ 

            if (first % second == 0) {
                    lcm = first;
                    break;
            }else if (second % first == 0)  
            {
                    lcm = second;
                    break;
            } else if (first > second)  
            {
                    countProduct = first * count;
                    count++;
                    if (countProduct % first == 0  && countProduct % second == 0)
                    {
                            lcm = countProduct;
                            product = lcm;
                    }
            } else
            {
                    countProduct = second * count;
                    count++;
                    if (countProduct % first == 0 && countProduct % second  == 0)
                    {
                    lcm = countProduct;
                            product = lcm;
                    }
            }
    }
            
    printf("GCD of %d and %d is %d\n", first, second, first*second / lcm);

    return 0;
```

}

What I found out so far is that when I assign 1 to `first` followed by any other number, the `lcm` variable does not get updated but remains the value during initialization.

Everything other set I did gave me the expected output except for this.

Thank you so much.

Comment: `scanf()` without cheking return code -> undefined behavior waiting to happen. (What happens when the user enters something that is not a number?)

Comment: What do you think the result of `some_number % 1` would be?

Comment: @DevSolar Thanks for painting that out. I have considered that but I haven't figured it out yet. I'm new to C and still learning.

Comment: @Bob__ wouldn't that be 0? If I enter 1 (first) and 2 onwards for the second variable, I get FPE. Other than that, I am getting the expected outcome

Comment: Good, so if `product % first` equals zero, the body of the `while` is not executed and `lcm` is still zero when `first*second / lcm` is executed, but it seems that you already know that. You should avoid both `/ 0` and `% 0`, so what are you asking, how to treat the cases where `first` or `second` are 1?

Comment: `scanf()` returns the number of successful conversions it has done. If that is less than the number of conversions in the format string (the "%" things), input has failed and the remaining variables *have not been initialized*. So, for the beginning, check that your `scanf()`'s (having only that one "%d") have returned 1, or abort. Later, when you know more about the language, you can try to recover from the input error (which unfortunately is not trivial). Generally speaking, it's easier to read full lines of input (`fgets()`) and then parse those (`strtol`).

Comment: As for posting code here, it's better to not have the program take input, but have the data it is working on *in the code itself*. Because right now we don't know (unless we try) whether it's *all* inputs that show the problem, or only specific ones.

Comment: Thanks @Bob__. I assigned a value of -1 to `product` before the while but I'm still getting the error. How do I fix this?

Comment: @DevSolarThank you. I'll take note of that. We haven't discussed those in class yet.